# select SQL table from php variable

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have selected a random table from a list/array and I want to be able to call this random table with the mysqli_query function i.e. select a table dynamically

Here is my code:

```
<?php
            $mysqli=mysqli_connect(HOST,USERNAME,PASSWORD,DATABASE);

            // Check connection
            if (mysqli_connect_errno($mysqli))
            {
                echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
            }

            // Looks at all prodcuts and selects those that have special offers enabled
            // Selects a random table from the array
            $tables_special = ["ajbs_products_console" ,"ajbs_products_console_games", "ajbs_products_pc", "ajbs_products_pc_games", "ajbs_products_pc_parts"];
            $rtable = $tables_special[floor (rand(0,count($tables_special)-1))];
            echo "<p>".$rtable." was selected</p>";


            $products = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM '".$rtable."'");


            echo "<p>".$products."</p>";
            while($productRow = mysqli_fetch_array($products))
            {
                if ($productRow['product_specials'] == 1)
                {
                    echo "<table>";
                    echo "<tr>";
                    echo "<td rowspan='2'><img src=" . $productRow['product_image'] . "/></td>";
                    echo "</tr>";
                    echo "<table border='1'>";
                    echo "<tr>";
                    echo "<td>Product Name</td>";
                    echo "<td>" . $productRow['product_name'] . "</td>";
                    echo "</tr>";
                    echo "<tr>";
                    echo "<td>Description</td>";
                    echo "<td>" . $productRow['product_description'] . "</td>";
                    echo "</tr>";
                    echo "</table>";
                }
            }

            mysqli_close($mysqli);
        ?>
```

Im at a loss of why this is not working

Thanks,

Bull

Comment: I highly recommend you change your password now.

Answer (score 3):

You should not quote table names with single quotes but with backticks, single quotes makes it a string instead of a table name;

Also, the function mysqli_query takes an extra parameter, the connection.

```
$products = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM '".$rtable."'");
```

should be;

```
$products = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM `".$rtable."`");
```

Comment: is still get an error:

ajbs_products_console was selected

Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in /usr/local/www/project/A.J.Bullock/ajbstudios/index.php on line 103

So it now seems thats not the problem. I think it has somin to do with the table being defined as a string in the array $tables_special But im not knowledgeable to know this for certain

Comment: @Bull Updated the answer, there were two separate errors in the row.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$products = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM ".$rtable);
```

Comment: Still not working, i guess i have to figure out another way of doing it. Thanks for the help though :)